# What’s the meaning of ‘somewhere between eight and 12 seconds’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following excerpt is from an article about Obama’s famous 2004 speech.

‘He seemed to have somewhere between eight and 12 seconds of political nicety in him for everyone before he would declare what he would rather be doing (“I need a nap”) and move on.’

In this context, what’s the meaning of ‘eight and twelve seconds’?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Stella. "between eight and twelve seconds" seems reasonably clear to me: it means 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 seconds. There is no special meaning in this context. Can you explain what you are having trouble understanding?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. My guessing was same as your explain. I just want to make it clear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the meaning in context is exactly what you would expect.

Comment: I’m very new to this forum. Do I need some action to close my question?

Comment: @Stella not at all. Just because *one* user thinks that a question should be closed does not mean others agree. Browse our [help], especially [this page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) to learn more about how the site in general and the closing of questions works.

Comment: It seems to emphasize that "He" (whoever "He" is) has little need for political nicety or is bored by it. Or at best enough to satisfy 8 - 12 seconds if necessary, which isn't long at all. More context would be helpful if you are looking for a hidden meaning.

Comment: It seems that the quote is *not* from Obama‘s speech, but a personal recollection of journalist Mark Leibovic, who interviewed Obama in the context of his first widely-noticed public appearance: https://nytimes.com/2016/07/27/magazine/the-speech-that-made-obama.html

Comment: Thank you, Stephie. Your link page is very helpful for me to understand this forum’s policy. And you are right. My except was from the above article. Sorry for my incorrect explanation. I hurried too much to post my question. As a foreigner, I sometimes can not be sure my understanding is correct when I meet this kind of indirect rhetoric.

Comment: I think the question is about the phrase **somewhere between** which seems a valid learner's question to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused because "Seconds" are "time" but the word "Somewhere" is used in the sentence instead of "When" or "Somewhen".

When I was a beginner at English, I thought that "Somewhere" or "where" are used for real or physical places only (e.g. This is the city where I born) but after some time, I realized that it can also be used for unreal places (e.g. I was in a situation where I had to run away) and a good example would be your sentence too.

Answer (score 0):

What does the phrase **somewhere between 8 and 12 seconds** mean?

We often speak of numbers as if they were on a *physical* scale, like a ruler or yardstick. In that sentence, a range of time, a duration, is being expressed spatially, and so you find the phrase **somewhere between**, which means at some *location* that is found between those two (temporal) points.

The word **somewhere** means "at some location". The exact location is not specified. It is intentionally vague or indefinite.

He would be polite for a brief time,  *approximately* 10 seconds, give or take a couple of seconds, and then he would say how he truly felt.

P.S. I don't mean to imply that the speaker visualizes a ruler, but that we easily transpose time into the linear.  We speak of **timelines** and say things like "It happened at some point between last Thursday evening and now".

Comment: That's why I included the word **yardstick**.  It's easy to type "yardstick" into Google and then click the -images- link. But even "ruler" does not pull up pictures of Trump or Merkel :)

Answer (score -3):

In this context, "seconds" are the units of time, not "second helpings" nor "second-rate goods".

By the way, all of these terms are derived from 2's ordinal number.
The unit of time is the result of a "second" division of an hour into 60 parts.  An hour consists of 60 minutes.  A minute consists of 60 seconds.